# How to find PC MAC address using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mac-address

Is there a way to retrieve system information like MAC Address, computer name, etc. from the host PC using jQuery?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, luckily not.

Comment: Yup, this would be a sandbox violation.

Comment: +1 browser-hosted javascript should never have that much visibility into a machine.  The universe would collapse under its own dark-matter weight.

Comment: you're right, I wasn't thinking maliciously as much of you obviously do (not a bad thing).  I work on the inside of a firewall and would only use this website for my own personal purposes and information gathering around my facility.

Comment: I came here because I need to 100% make sure a user only gets a free voucher once from a specific device. Cookies aren't reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=134120

```
var strComputer = ".";
var objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\cimv2");
var e = new Enumerator(objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter","WQL",48));

for (;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext())
{   objItem = e.item();
    WScript.Echo ("MACAddress: " + objItem.MACAddress)
}
```

Comment: That can only work on Windows. And not that it will work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I faces This Problem, I solved it by create Applet using signed Jar grant him all the permission,but in java script and jquery there is only activex but it works on ie in the other browser it's not working.